# ARRAY_SUM() EXPECTS PARAMETER 1 TO BE ARRAY, NULL GIVEN

Tags: php

Strange issue, this runs fine on my local installation but on my live server it throws an error when the value is 0.

ARRAY_SUM() EXPECTS PARAMETER 1 TO BE ARRAY, NULL GIVEN

```
 <?php 

function author_rating_total() {
   $user_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
   $query = array (
       'author' => $user_id,
       'suppress_filters' => 'true', //lets skip some unnessecery sql queries
       'posts_per_page' => -1
   );
   $queryObject = new WP_Query($query); while($queryObject->have_posts()) : $queryObject->the_post();

   $post_ratings_data = get_post_custom(get_the_id());
   $post_ratings_score = intval($post_ratings_data['epicredvote'][0]);

   $ratings_array[] = $post_ratings_score;

   endwhile; 

   $ratings_sum = array_sum($ratings_array);

   if ($ratings_sum > 0) {
         $ratings_sum = '' . $ratings_sum;
   }  

   echo $ratings_sum;   

   wp_reset_query();
}
?>
```

Comment: Yeah it happens when there's a zero value to be output.

Comment: ensure `$ratings_array` is defined and is array before applying

Comment: I can't just check if the array has a null value with something like if(!array_filter($ratings_sum)) {
    echo 'This array contains no value';
} ?

Answer (score 0):

If you define $ratings_array before your while loop then it should work

```
$ratings_array = array();
$wpQuery = etc
```

**OR** if you wrap a conditional statement round the array_sum():

```
$ratings_sum = 0;
if (is_array($ratings_array)){
    $ratings_sum = array_sum(etc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just done a conditional to attempt the display if the value wasn't null.

```
if (count($ratings_sum) === 0) {

    echo author_rating_total();

}
```